# Как реализовать поиск доменов по IP-адресам?

Tags: поиск, php, mysql

Подскажите, как будет проще реализовать подобный поиск:

Есть база данных MySQL в ней 10 000 записей в виде домена, нужно найти домены по IP-адресу. Переформирование базы данных не прокатит. Думал выбрать все домены, прогнать через `gethostbyaddr()` но не лопнет ли php от 10 000? Может есть примеры по проще?

Comment: У меня вот прям сейчас прайс загоняется и обновляется на 73000 позиции, и не лопнул )). Если боитесь, то запустите и отойдите ))) А вообще, можно же сделать порционно, по 100 записей за раз, например. Если совсем БД не трогать, то gethostbyaddr получаете хост и поиск по бд - это милисекундное дело, другое дело, что если строго по этим 10.000 доменам поиск, то при большой нагрузке все-таки правильнее было бы им сделать IP соответствие в БД и время от времени обновлять.

Comment: вот в этом то и дело, я думал о порциях. но может есть что то другое. Думаю попробую по 100 записей, если других вариантов не найдется. :((((

Comment: Попробуйте решение Sphinx - очень удобно работать

Comment: @IOleg sphinx человеку надо получить ip для доменов в б.д. а не искать их

Answer (score 2):

а вообще вопрос решаем довольно просто. создаете поле с соответствием и шелл на php. Добавляете вывод в виде echo и запускаете его через шелл `php -f yourScript.php`. В начале скрипта убираем лимиты памяти и времени. Ну и далее пьем чай и смотрим прогресс )